# CCAvenue payment gateway integration with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, ccavenue

I want to integrate the ccavenue payment gateway  into my rails app give some guide line for how to implement the gateway

I had tried Activemerchant_ccavenue but don't get success ..... sample example with integration is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can find details of how we did it at http://www.dealbuddie.com here - http://dealbuddie.tumblr.com/post/56908130601/integrating-ccavenue-with-ruby-on-rails-site

Comment: I also want to use CC Avenue, but this link won't open. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Example Usage is given on the readme page itself:
create an initializer, like `initializers/payment.rb`. Add the following lines:

```
  ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Ccavenue.setup do |cca|
    cca.merchant_id = M_blahpache_5678 #your CCAvenue merchant id from the working key generation page
    cca.work_key = 6abc0ty90e0v7jk9hj #your CCAvenue working key
  end
  CCAVENUE_ACCOUNT = 'youraccountname'
```

[CCAvenue integration for ActiveMerchant - README](https://github.com/kevivmatrix/active_merchant_ccavenue/blob/master/README.rdoc)

so what all have you tried? What errors you get?

Comment: uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Helper

Comment: This library is old & not actively maintained, so will have to dive into the source & make it work. if you know what I mean